# Put whats in my .txt file in to my listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I've been looking for awhile but everything I find doesn't work. I'm trying to take the text from my .txt file and have it placed in my listbox when the form loads.

I tried `const string sPath = "TextFile1.txt"; listBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(sPath);` but it won't work the listbox is blank when I open the form. I want it to be able to get the current directory of the .txt so it will work on any computer. Thanks.

Comment: From the above, the file should be copied into the bin/debug directory when the program runs, is the file there?  Have you set "Copy to output directory"? Are you using WinForms or WPF?  I presume Winforms because WPF ListBox doesn't have .Text.  Anyways you need to go *ListBox.Items.Add(...)*.

Answer (score 1):

Use streamreader , read each line into an array and set the array to the Listbox.
Listbox.items.add (Array[x])
I'm assuming there are no separators in the text ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = File.ReadAllLines("TextFile1.txt");
this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(content);
```